# How to encode string to RFC 3986 in Flutter or Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, uri

I am trying to encode a string to  RFC 3986. I have found the method Uri.encodeComponent but that encodes the string to RFC 2396. 
Basically, I am looking for an alternate method for a method in PHP i.e rawurlencode. In php this method encode the string to RFC 3986. Is there any such method in Dart or Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer from Dart SDK gitter Channel.
Use Uri.encodeQueryComponent it is the same as encodeComponent but instead of using a RFC 2396 compatible table it uses RFC 3986.

Comment: No, it is Html4. space --> +